# jQuery hide slide messing with element position

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Code sample at: http://jsbin.com/dadih/43

I want to be able to click "Yes" or "No" and have the other button not clicked slide hide before the second set of buttons shows up.

Once the hide animation begins, it looks like the non clicked button wraps to the next line and I cannot figure out why.

Your help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons need to be floated:

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">   

  <button class="response" id="r1">Yes</button>
  <button class="response" id="r2">No</button>

  <button class="result">Resolved</button>
  <button class="result">Not Resolved</button>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.result{
   display:none;
}

button{
   /*display:inline;*/
   height:30px;
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;
}

.buttons{
   width:100%;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

jQuery:

```
//$(function() {
    $('#accordion').accordion();
//});

$('.response').click(function() {
   var currentButton = "#" + this.id;

   $('.response').not(currentButton).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200, function(){      
       $('.result').css("display","inline-block");      
       $(currentButton).css("background","dimgrey"); 
   }); 
});
```

Running sample: http://jsbin.com/fetux/1

Comment: Thanks Reza. Note that if you click on the "NO" button once the slide animation is complete for the buttons going away,the ""Yes" button jumps left. Is there away to make that transition left smoother?